# Is it safe to negate the result of an && (logical and) operation?

Tags: c, logical-operators, return-type

I vaguely know that the return type of a Boolean operator is `int` in C, but is it guaranteed to be the unflavored `int`, and not, say, `unsigned int`?

I am generally concerned if I am allowed to negate the result of a Boolean operation and expect it to be either `0` or `-1`, and not `2^32 - 1`. See the following example:

```c
int main(void) {
    int a = -(5 == 5);
    // Is "a" guaranteed to be -1 here?
}
```

Comment: The C standard states that false is 0 and true is 1, so you're safe either way, but it is of type `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of a comparison and logical operators is the value `0` or `1` of type `int`. `int` is specified to hold at least the integer range [−32,767, +32,767].

`-(5 == 5)` is therefore always `-1`, and `-(5 == 4)` is `0`,

Doing this is however confusing. The results of these operators is usually treated in a boolean-like way, and using the numerical value of the result might make it harder to understand the code.

Using the ternary operator may make the intent more clear:

```
(5 == num) ? -1 : 0
```

Using a number of compilers on the [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8qnqSG), I didn't see a difference in the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

See [C11 6.5.8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8) and [C11 6.5.9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9).

Yes, the operator `==` yields a result of type `int` with value `0` or `1`.